# Windows Phone 7 BarCode scan library or capability?

Tags: windows-phone-7, barcode, barcode-scanner

Is there a good BarCode scan capability or library for Windows Phone 7?

I assume the library will scan a taken image from the phone, and return a BarCode for the image, if available.

Also, is there a good primer on scanning Barcodes and using them within an app (how to map to a vendor, product, etc), which is applicable for WP7 or .NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WP7 SDK does not have the capability built in to read a barcode from an image.

The SDK does have the capability to take the picture though, using CameraCaptureTask.. there is a sample for doing this here.

[How to: Use Launchers for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769550%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Also, you could take a look at .net projects on the net that offer the capability to read a barcode form a supplied image. For example..

[Reading Barcodes from an Image](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BarcodeImaging3.aspx)

Microsoft probably won't develop this capability since it can readily be provided by 3rd Party SDKs and there is fairly health barcode expertise out there in the community already.

Comment: i discovered that, but I have seen some libraries around that *might* work, and i was wondering if anyone has played with any, or heard of any future ability which might be whisper or on a OS roadmap.

Comment: That additional information is very helpful.  I'll be trying that tonight!  Thank you!

Comment: Cool... hopefully that library doesn't use any APIs that are unavailable on the phone platform. If it does you could look at removing the dependency (being open source) or check same for other projects.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote the [PhraseMeme Scanner](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6T_v4x9JtLQ) app that was mentioned, and yes it is based on the ZXing library. The app has now been released to [the marketplace](http://www.wpappshub.com/tools/phrasememe-scanner), and more information can be found at http://PhraseMeme.com/Scanner

I also uploaded the Silverlight port of the ZXing library to http://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/. The project includes sample code for using the library as well as a BarcodePhotoChooser XAML/CS page for displaying and choosing sample barcodes since the emulator does not support the camera. I plan on submitting bug fixes and additional code to this project so that others can also use it in their Windows Phone 7 or Silverlight applications.

Answer (score 5):

There are several applications in the marketplace having this feature, maybe one of them list the component used to read the barcodes:
http://wp7applist.com/search/?q=barcode

There's a C# version of ZXing from Google compatible with Windows Phone 7:
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/csharp

http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2010/08/wp7-zxing-barcode.html

Update this app seems to use ZXing and will release their code:
http://www.phrasememe.com/scanner/