# How to read barcode in a WP7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Recommend an Open Source .NET Barcode Reader Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191192/recommend-an-open-source-net-barcode-reader-library)
>   [Windows Phone 7 BarCode scan library or capability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419707/windows-phone-7-barcode-scan-library-or-capability)

I need to read the barcodes in my WP7 application. Is there any library available for reading barcodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifcally for WP7 no. There are open source .net librarys arround but they would need to be complied for the .net compact framework. You could borrow code but there arent any that would work "as is"