# Selecting Mobile Development Frameworks

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, mobile, frameworks

I am new to developing mobile apps. But I have plenty of ideas and coding experience in php, javascript, html5 and other web technologies. Currently I am planning an application which requires to use lots of hardware features which include microphone, camera, usb/otg, wifi/network, proximity sensors etc. AFAIK there are two kinds of app that exist in the market today:

- One that do not use hardware sensors at all and only use display methods and network communications to work as applications.
- Others make use of one or more hardware sensors.

Now I want to know which rad frameworks are available which could provide best of both worlds an individual comparison for both types will be good. Also if the same framework can co exist on other platforms (maybe iOS or windows) that will be awesome.

I went through multiple app frameworks that can get me to develop apps in no time like jquerymobile, enyo, appium, etc. But I could not find upto what level of hardware sensor api can they provide to the app built over them.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this interesting [Mobile Framework Comparison Chart](http://www.markus-falk.com/mobile-frameworks-comparison-chart/).  It compares the OS's, the supported languages and the supported hardware features.

For your specific needs, I think indeed Rhodes or Phonegap are good choices. There are other discussions about which framework is the best, [I suggest you read them and make a choice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697801/rhomobile-vs-phonegap-considerations/12618361#12618361)

Comment: actually quite interesting... I love it, I could find only Rhodes as something that caters my needs... What do you say?

Answer (score 1):

You may check out [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

This framework uses HTML, CSS and Javascript.
I've never tried it, but it seems to fulfill your needs.

It supports:

- Android
- Blackberry
- iOS
- Windows Phone 7/8
- Windows 8 and others.

Regarding sensors, it offers APIs for:

- accelerometer
- camera
- capture
- compass
- geolocation
- storage.

More information [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html).