# Include barcode scanner in mobile web app without going native?

Tags: mobile, cordova, sencha-touch, barcode, barcode-scanner

is there any possibility to include a Barcode scanner in a mobile web app without going native?

As a former Android developer I know how to [integrate e.g ZXing](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/share-with-intents.html) in my native code and I also know that there are [Barcode scanner plugins for Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311380/phonegap-barcode-scanner) out there. They all have something in common: you need a Development Environment for each mobile platform AND you have to get your hands dirty with native development. Furthermore you cannot use [PohneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/).

I am searching for a standalone HTML5 mobile app approach. More specific, I try to find a way to outsource the Barcode scanning from the native platform. An example: I can access the camera with HTML5 apps, so is there any web service out there which, for instance, receives Barcode pictures and returns the code?

Can anyone tell me if sth like that exists or is in progress?

Any helpful information appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barcode requires camera access. HTML5's WebCam API is still very new and it's not very widely supported on desktop browsers and much less on mobile browsers too. You can't depend on it being available.

After seeing your question, I have tested the Camera sample app in my HTC OneX. And, it worked only in Opera mobile browser. And I learnt that Opera is the only mobile browser that supports HTML5 camera extension.

You can also test visiting.

http://people.opera.com/danield/html5/explode/

I recommend to use interface framework like PhoneGap, if you really have the plan to make it native.

Answer (score 1):

Using my Galaxy S3, running on 4.1 (Jelly Bean), I've been able to access the camera directly from my web app using HTML5.

[HTML 5 native camera access from web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676036/can-you-launch-the-native-camera-app-from-an-html-5-web-app)